# How to make a $http.get request with a one to many relationship

Tags: angularjs

I have a one-to-many relationship, "Job" can have many "JobItems". When I select a Job to edit a modal opens with its properties, including the JobItems. I need to make a request that returns the JobItems for only that Job. My question is how to tell the request to retrieve only the JobItems with that JobId? The selected Job (JobId) is put in sessionStorage when the modal is opened. So that is easily accessible.

How to access the selected JobId

```
$scope.job.JobId
```

ngTable that retrieves JobItems(currently it retrieves all JobItems in the database)

```
// Table
$scope.tableParams = new ngTableParams({
    page: 1,            // show first page
    count: 100,          // count per page
    sorting: {
        foo: 'asc'     // initial sorting
    }
}, {
    counts: [], // length of data
    getData: function ($defer, params) {
        $http.get('/api/apiJobItem/')
           .success(function (data, status) {
               var orderedData = params.sorting() ? $filter('orderBy')(data, params.orderBy()) : data;
               // update table params
               params.total(data.length);
               $defer.resolve(orderedData.slice((params.page() - 1) * params.count(), params.page() * params.count()));
           });
    }
});
```

Update Job JSON

```
$$hashKey: "object:96"$id: "7"ChangeOrders: Array[0]Customer: "Colorado"CustomerEmployeePM: ObjectJobCity: "Houston"JobContractDate: "2014-12-03T18:53:09.43"JobId: "068a75cf-7b8f-4752-923b-75eedbc43ec1"JobInsProgram: "OCIP"JobIsHidden: nullJobItems: Array[12]0: Object$id: "11"Job: nullJobId: "068a75cf-7b8f-4752-923b-75eedbc43ec1"JobItemBackOrder: nullJobItemId: 93JobItemIsHidden: nullQBRFQGROUPCOMBINESIZES: 0QBRFQGROUPITEMSCOMBINESIZES: 5464QBRFQLINESUPPLIERPARTNUMBER: "HW12"QBRFQLINESUPPLIERQUOTENOTES: "Pricing is good through 4th qtr 2014."QBRFQLINESUPPLIERQUOTEQTY: 0QBRFQLINESUPPLIERQUOTEUNITPRICE: 38QBRFQLINESUPPLIERQUOTEUOM: "hank"__proto__: Object1: Object2: Object3: Object4: Object5: Object6: Object7: Object8: Object9: Object10: Object11: Objectlength: 12__proto__: Array[0]JobName: "Job Alpha"JobNumber: 9999
```

Inline Edit ngTable

```
   <table ng-table="tableParams" class="table" style="margin-right:20px;margin-left:20px">
                <tbody ng-repeat="jobItem in $data">
                    <tr id="tr{{jobItem.JobItemId}}" ng-class-odd="'odd'" ng-class-even="'even'">
                        <td class="rowTd" data-title="'ID'">{{jobItem.ESOURCELINEID}}</td>
                        <td class="rowTd" data-title="'SIZES'">{{jobItem.QBRFQGROUPCOMBINESIZES}}</td>
                        <td class="rowTd" data-title="'NUMBER'">{{jobItem.QBRFQLINESUPPLIERPARTNUMBER}}</td>
                        <td class="rowTd" data-title="'EXPIRE'">{{jobItem.QBRFQLINESUPPLIERQUOTEEXPIRE}}</td>
                        <td class="rowTd" data-title="'NOTES'">{{jobItem.QBRFQLINESUPPLIERQUOTENOTES}}</td>
                        <td class="rowTd" data-title="'QUOTE QTY'">{{jobItem.QBRFQLINESUPPLIERQUOTEQTY}}</td>
                        <td class="rowTd" data-title="'UNIT PRICE'">{{jobItem.QBRFQLINESUPPLIERQUOTEUNITPRICE}}</td>
                        <td class="rowTd" data-title="'UID'">{{jobItem.QBRFQLINEUID}}</td>
                        <td class="rowTd">
                            <input style="height:30px;padding-top:4px" class="btn-Custom" type=button id="editRowBtn{{jobItem.JobItemId}}" value="edit"
                                   ng-click="setEditId(jobItem.JobItemId)">
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr ng-show="editId===jobItem.JobItemId" ng-if="editId===jobItem.JobItemId">
                        <td colspan="7" ng-include src="'Modals/JobModalTabs/editRow.html'"></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

So two solutions for that.

**1, the better one**
You change your api that return jobs, this call return jobs and they contain an array with their jobitems. Like that no other calls.

**2,Middle**

You just implement an endpoint (url) on your api to get jobitem linked to the kib so something like :
*/api/apiJobItem/$scope.job.JobId*

And you implement this call in an angular service : *jobitems*

**3. the slower one**

the second one and **the worst !**

is to get jobitems from your job so your job look like something like :

```
{
  id: XXX,
  name : "XXX",
  jobitems : [
   jobitem_id1,
   jobitem_id2,
   jobitem_id3
 ]
}
```

And the when you receive your list of jobsitems (like you do), you can check something like:

```
for(all items in jobitemslist){
 if(current job item is present in job.Jobitems){
  add job item in array
 }
}
return array
```

Comment: I just posted the Job JSON.I forgot to mention i do have access to the JobItems through the selected Job. So how would I access them through a table? would it be something as simple as ng-repeat"jobItem in jobArray.JobItems"

Comment: Yes you should just do a ng-repeat on the list and display it in a table as you want.

Comment: Well now i remember why i nees help with that. I am using ngtable. So i am using the $data syntax in ng repeat. How can i change this

Comment: which version of ngTable do you use ?